# Should I delete my question if it was resolved with a comment that isn't related to the original question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, etiquette, vote-to-delete

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32632880/27457) today about LINQ-to-Entities left joins that (I thought) was specifically about the syntax of using DefaultIfEmpty().  A commenter proposed an avenue that is totally unrelated to DefaultIfEmpty(), but that I found solves my problem by eliminating the need for it.  Meanwhile, someone posted an answer to the question.  My instinct says that I should delete my question, but it's anathema to remove questions from SO, especially when they have answers that might help someone else in the future.  Should I delete the question, answer it myself, wait to see if other answers surface...or what?

Comment: You could encourage the person who left the comment to submit it as an answer so you can accept it. If they don't after a few days, you could self-answer and note that you got the answer from the comment.

Comment: What @BSMP suggests should be done only if the question and answer are written in such a way that the link between the problem and its solution is clear. (This may mean having to edit the question to make the link clear.)

Comment: @Louis yes, that's what I thought.  I don't see any real use in editing the question here, though, hence my confusion...is this one of those times where deleting would be OK?

Comment: @AJ And is the answer (not the comment, but the actual answer) on your question actually helpful, given what is in the question?

Comment: @Louis - no, I don't find it useful, as it does not directly answer my question and links to an example that I 1) found before I asked in the first place and 2) don't believe addresses my specific situation.  I would have upvoted it had I thought it helpful :-)

Comment: @AJ Given what you say, and the fact that I do not know LINQ and cannot offer an opinion that differs from yours, I'd say delete.

Comment: @Louis I agree.  Now the ultimate irony: should I delete this question? ;-D

Comment: @AJ. Hmm... I'm not sure about this. Maybe someone who does know LINQ and can see deleted questions would see a way to edit the question??

Comment: So in other words you post an x/y question that was solved by doing z. It might be more useful to answer it explaining why **y** was the wrong choice and why **z** is the right choice.